# How should I approach solving matrices and linear systems problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There are 2 matrices and 1 vector:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 5 & -7 & -4 &  9 \\ 
 6 & -8 & -7 &  5 \\ 
 4 & -4 & -9 & -9 \\ 
-9 & 11 & 16 &  7
\end{bmatrix}, 
\quad B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 9 & 11 & -6 & -7 & 13 \\
-7 & -8 &  5 &  6 & -9 \\
11 &  7 & -7 & -9 & -6 \\
-3 &  4 &  1 &  8 &  7
\end{bmatrix}, 
\quad
v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

1. For each $b \in \mathbb{R}^4$, does the equation $Bx = b$ have a solution?
   Row Reduced $B$ =\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -7/13 &  0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 & -2/13 &  0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
2. Solve the equation $Ax = v$ by reducing the augmented matrix corresponding to this linear system.
   Row Reduced $Ax = v$ =\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 &  4/3 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 &  -5/3 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 7/3 & 0\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
3. Solve the equation $Bx = v$ by reducing the augmented matrix corresponding to this linear system.
   Row Reduced $Bx = v$ =$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
    1 & 0 & -7/13 &  0 & 0 & -1525/156\\ 
    0 & 1 & -2/13 &  0 & 0 &1115/156\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &-5\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & -29/12
   \end{array}
   \right] $$
   This content is very new to me. I'm good at getting it to the row-reduced echelon form but solving and interpreting it from that point, not so much. I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: This is a very general question.  And if you're new to it, then I advise you to read through the material that you have (your textbook, or online source) to learn.

Comment: Also please don't ask multiple questions in one question and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math expressions.

Comment: As you are good at getting to reduced form, you should save us the work by doing it for your matrices and including the results in your question. That will make it easier for someone to post the interpretations, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good idea, Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're satisfied with your answer, but inspired by your post, I decided to make a [long and comprehensive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856127/how-to-interpret-row-echelon-form/) to the question of how to interpret row echelon forms of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve.

(1) For reduced matrix B, we know there are four rows and five columns, so either there is no solution due to the contradiction, or there will be infinitely many solutions due to the free variable. It's easy to determine that there is a free variable, which would be $x_3$. So yes, there are infinitely many solutions.

(2) For the second question, I would like to remind you that $v$ should not be a $4\times 5$ matrix, which will be indicating that $x$ is a $4\times5$ matrix. So I suppose you want to show that the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix is the matrix you put in the question. However, the answer is obvious.

There is no such a $x$ matrix satisfies this equation because you can never satisies the forth row, which is $0=1$.

(3)
Since we can't have a row which has a pivot located at the third colomn and the elements in the third colomn are not always 0, so we will have the free variable. The solution will be:

\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac{7}{13}\cdot x_3 - \frac{1525}{156}\\
x_2 &= \frac{2}{13}\cdot x_3 + \frac{1115}{156}\\
x_4 &= -5\\
x_5 &= -\frac{29}{12}
\end{align}

Hope this will help you. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This aligns with what I just found myself and now I am confident in my approach. Thanks again for your help!